# Excel, about baseball and innings pitched

Tags: excel

In baseball, innings a pitcher throws are counted in thirds. This is because a pitcher needs 3 outs to complete one inning. However, the standard notation for showing this is not in thirds. 51 innings and 2 outs, is not shown as 51.66, but instead as 51.2. The number after the decimal is the number of outs after the last inning pitched the pitcher got. This means that it will go to 52 IP when it gains .1, not .8, because he needs 1 more out to get the next inning, not 8.

I have a list of IP for a specific pitcher, which I have used DOLLARDE to convert from baseball notation to a fraction. Meaning, 51.2 for me is now shown as 51.667. This is useful for adding the amount of innings he has thrown in a season, by making it accurate, but it isn't a form baseball fans are used to seeing. How would I convert this back into 51.2 automatically, and not by hand? Shown in Q2
[image: excel]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use DOLLARDE(A1,3) to convert from a fraction to a decimal, how about using the inverse DOLLARFR(B1,3) to convert back to a fraction? That seems to be the easiest.

[image]

Comment: thanks, that worked. How would i set it up so the number would automatically change when i enter in more data points?

Comment: Explore the use of Excel Tables. Insert > Table will turn your data into a table. Formulas can reference a table column instead of A1:A10 and the reference will grow and shrink with the table.